# Dispatcher servlet's forward method takes much CPU

Tags: java, spring, performance, servlets, jetty

VisualVM shows me following picture:

[image: VisualVM screen]

Why does it show that Distatcher servlet's forward() method takes the most of CPU? I looked into sources, the 1st forward() method in my call tree just calls another forward() method with additional parameter. I don't see how it can take CPU. Please help.

The source of the 1st forward() method from my call tree that somehow takes CPU:

```
public void forward(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    forward(request, response, Handler.FORWARD);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because each forward involves a RequestDispatcher that locates the resource on disk you are forwarding to. Not necessarily all the resources (JSP's etc) are cached in memory at the point when you invoked the forward.

Subsequently it also needs to process the JSP or servlet you are forwarding to. I don't see any other reason.